# Get Members of a Dynamic Distribution List

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list of the users of 2 different DDL using PS for Exchange.  I keep seeing the same code pop up in all my searches (see below).  However, the results that are returned are of all the users in my Exchange 2010.  So what am I doing wrong??

```
$SRA = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "DDL_name"
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $SRA.RecipientFilter
```

Comment: Is "DLL_name" a security group?

Comment: Try `echo $SRA.RecipientFilter` and see what the result is. This will show what is the applied filter and a clue why all your users are being returned.

Comment: Looking deeper into what the issue could be, it looks like the DDLs were created in the OU of the users that are to be added.  The type is a msExchangeDynamicDistributionList.  We have another OU that holds all the DLs except for these 2. I'm guessing this could be part of the issue?